# How do I get the result of this this Random Numbers generated in Javascript? I mean so I can alert or send to console

Tags: javascript, html, random

This piece of javascript successfully generated random number but I'm having challenge in fetching the variable value so I can use it as desired. below is the working code:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let output = document.querySelector('#output');
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    let step1 = max - min + 1;
    let step2 = Math.random() * step1;
    let result = Math.floor(step2) + min;
    return result;
}
function createArrayOfNumbers(start, end){
    let myArray = [];
    for(let i = start; i <= end; i++) { 
        myArray.push(i);
    }
    return myArray;
}
let numbersArray = createArrayOfNumbers(1,10);
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(numbersArray.length == 0){
        output.innerText = 'No More Random Numbers';
        return;
    }
    let randomIndex = getRandomNumber(0, numbersArray.length-1);
    let randomNumber = numbersArray[randomIndex];
    numbersArray.splice(randomIndex, 1)
    output.innerText = randomNumber;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Generate</button>
    <h1 id="output" style="text-align: center">Random Number</h1>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing but the easiest would be to create a global variable outside the function and then when that random number is generated assign that number to that global variable you can write it like this:

```
var myvariable = 0;
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let output = document.querySelector('#output');

//all of your code and then at the end

numbersArray.splice(randomIndex, 1)
output.innerText = randomNumber;
myvariable = randomNumber;
});
```

Now this variable is accessible outside the function. Hope that helps!